# How to move woocommerce H1 category title inside the main content (above the description)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

this is my first question. I need your help because I would love to move the category shop title in woocommerce above the description. Right now I have on the top of the page: title, breadcrumb, filter and then, inside the main content I have the category description. I would like to have the title and category description together. Is it possible? Thanks

I know that with some hooks I can move the description after the main content. I would love to do something similar with the title. Thanks.

Comment: Can you woocomerce hook fucntion

Comment: https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-single-product-page/